# Remover filho de uma ExpandedListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Olá, gostaria de saber como faz para remover um subitem de uma ExpandedListView, em outras palavras remover o item do adapter, sendo que o adapter recebe um `Map<Categoria, List<SubCategoria>>` e então dar um `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Fragment da lista

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subcategoria_despesa, container, false);
    mListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listDes);
    refreshLista();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private void refreshLista() {
    CategoriaDAO cDAO = new CategoriaDAO(getContext());
    SubCategoriaDAO sDAO = new SubCategoriaDAO(getContext());
    List<Categoria> cList = cDAO.getLista(1);
    collection = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Categoria c : cList){
        List<SubCategoria> sList = sDAO.getLista(c.getId());
        collection.put(c, sList);
    }
    SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter adapter = new SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter(getContext(), cList, collection);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter da Lista

```
public class SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Map<Categoria, List<SubCategoria>> mCollection;
private List<Categoria> mList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;


public SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<Categoria> list, Map<Categoria, List<SubCategoria>> collection) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCollection = collection;
    this.mList = list;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mCollection.get(mList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final SubCategoria subCategoria = (SubCategoria) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    ViewHolderItem holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategoria_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCat);
        holder.idItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        holder.btItem = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opcsubcat);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvItem.setText(subCategoria.getNome());
    holder.idItem.setText(String.valueOf(subCategoria.getId()));
    final View finalConvertView = convertView;
    holder.btItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.subcat_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.editarSub:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, EditaSubcategoriaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id", subCategoria.getId());
                            intent.putExtra("idcat", subCategoria.getIdCategoria());
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case R.id.apagarSub:
                            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                            ab.setTitle("Apagar subcategoria?");
                            ab.setMessage("Todas os lançamentos dessa subcategoria serão apagados.");
                            ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    SubCategoriaDAO dao = new SubCategoriaDAO(mContext);
                                    LancamentoDAO dao1 = new LancamentoDAO(mContext);
                                    dao1.deleteAllBySubcategoria(subCategoria.getId());
                                    dao.deletar(subCategoria);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            ab.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            ab.show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mCollection.get(mList.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Categoria categoria = (Categoria) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ViewHolderGroup holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.tvGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
        holder.idGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idc);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvGroup.setText(categoria.getNome());
    holder.idGroup.setText(String.valueOf(categoria.getId()));


    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    listView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, EditaSubcategoriaActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("idcat", categoria.getId());
            mContext.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("LOGE", position + "");
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

class ViewHolderGroup {
    TextView tvGroup;
    TextView idGroup;
}

class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView tvItem;
    TextView idItem;
    ImageButton btItem;
}
```

Ao clicar em apagar eu excluo a subcategoria do banco, mas não achei uma forma de excluí-la do adapter para poder atualizar a expandedlistview.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclua estes dois métodos na classe *SubcategoriaExpandableAdapter*.

```
public void removerSubCategorias(int groupPosition) {
    mCollection.get(mList.get(groupPosition)).clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removerSubCategoria(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    mCollection.get(mList.get(groupPosition)).remove(childPosition);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Se quer eliminar a `List<SubCategoria>` toda, ficando a *Categoria* sem itens(sub-categorias) use `removerSubCategorias(groupPosition);`.

Se quer eliminar um item(sub-categoria) da `List<SubCategoria>`, ficando a *Categoria* com menos um item(sub-categoria) use `removerSubCategoria(groupPosition, childPosition);`

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou como eu queria, obrigado @ramaral.

Comment: e se eu for atualizar um item, como procedo?

Comment: Depende. Coloque nova pergunta e dê detalhes de como/onde está a fazer essa alteração.